# delete a specific entry in the map,but the iterator must point to the next element after the deletion

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary

#### Duplicate:

> [What happens if you call erase on a map element while iterating from begin to end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263945/what-happens-if-you-call-erase-on-a-map-element-while-iterating-from-begin-to-e)
>
> [How to filter items from a stdmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180516/how-to-filter-items-from-a-stdmap)

I have a map `map1<string,vector<string>>` i have a iterator for this map "itr".
i want to delete the entry from this map which is pointed by "itr".
i can use the function map1.erase(itr); after this line the iterator "itr" becomes invalid.
as per my requirement in my project,the iterator must point to the next element. can any body help me regerding this
thans in advance:)
santhosh

Answer (score 5):

You can post-increment the iterator while passing it as argument to erase:

```
myMap.erase(itr++)
```

This way, the element that was pointed by `itr` before the erase is deleted, and the iterator is incremented to point to the next element in the map. If you're doing this in a loop, beware not to increment the iterator twice.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180516/how-to-filter-items-from-a-stdmap#180772) from a similar question, or what has been responded to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263945/what-happens-if-you-call-erase-on-a-map-element-while-iterating-from-begin-to-e).

Answer (score 2):

```
map<...>::iterator tmp(iter++);
map1.erase(tmp);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple Answer:

```
map.erase(iter++);  // Post increment. Increments iterator,
                    // returns previous value for use in erase method
```

Asked and answered before:
[What happens if you call erase on a map element while iterating from begin to end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263945/what-happens-if-you-call-erase-on-a-map-element-while-iterating-from-begin-to-e)
[How to filter items from a stdmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180516/how-to-filter-items-from-a-stdmap)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <boost/next_prior.hpp>

map<string,vector<string> >::iterator next = boost::next(itr);
map1.erase(iter);
iter = next;
```