# Can I continue to use an iterator after an item has been deleted from std::multimap<>?

Tags: c++, stl, multimap

Can I continue to use an multimap iterator even after a call to multimap::erase()?  For example:

```
Blah::iterator iter;
for ( iter = mm.begin();
      iter != mm.end();
      iter ++ )
{
    if ( iter->second == something )
    {
        mm.erase( iter );
    }
}
```

Should this be expected to run correctly, or is the iterator invalidated following the call to erase?  Reference sites like http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/multimap/erase.html are strangely quiet on this topic of the lifespans of iterators, or the effects of constructive/destructive methods on iterators.

Comment: "strangely quiet"  Love it!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Multimap.html

```
Multimap has the important property that inserting a new element
into a multimap does not invalidate iterators that point to existing
elements. Erasing an element from a multimap also does not invalidate
any iterators, except, of course, for iterators that actually point to
the element that is being erased.
```

So it should look like this:

```
Blah::iterator iter;
for ( iter = mm.begin();iter != mm.end();)
{
    if ( iter->second == something )
    {
        mm.erase( iter++ );
        // Use post increment. This increments the iterator but
        // returns a copy of the original iterator to be used by
        // the erase method
    }
    else
    {
        ++iter;   // Use Pre Increment for efficiency.
    }
}
```

Also see:
[What happens if you call erase() on a map element while iterating from begin to end?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263945/what-happens-if-you-call-erase-on-a-map-element-while-iterating-from-begin-to-e)

and

[delete a specific entry in the map,but the iterator must point to the next element after the deletion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268898/delete-a-specific-entry-in-the-map-but-the-iterator-must-point-to-the-next-elemen#269717)

Comment: Sorry to question you, but the post-increment of the iter doesn't result in an increment of an iterator that has now been invalidated?  I see your commented block at lines 7-9, but must admit I didn't know this.

Comment: Question as much as possable:-)

Comment: From the draft standard (n2521) Section 5.2.6: Increment and decrement. The value of a postﬁx ++ expression is the value of its operand. [ Note: the value obtained is a copy of the original value 
— end note ]

Comment: Note that all arguments to methods/functions must be fully evaluated before the method/function is called. So the above works.

Answer (score 1):

C++ Standard 23.1.2.8:

> The insert members shall not affect the validity of iterators and references to the container, and the erase members shall
>   invalidate only iterators and references to the erased elements.

This is a common requirement for all associative containers, and std::multimap is one of them.

Comment: Did you notice that iter++ is called *after* iter has been invalidated? Are you sure that the standard explicitly permits this?

Comment: Of course not. Standard guarantees, that all iterators except those which point to erased elements, are correct.

Comment: In this case, a direct answer to the OPs question would probably have earned you more rep...