# Why does the g++ 4.0 version of map<T>::erase(map::<T> iterator) not return a iterator?

Tags: c++, gcc, stl

I'm porting a medium-sized C++ project from Visual Studio 2005 to MacOS, XCode / GCC 4.0.

One of the differences I have just stumbled across has to do with erasing an element from a map. In Visual Studio I could erase an element specified by an iterator and assign the return value to the iterator to get the position of the next element. This way the iterator would not point to some invalid address after erasing.

In other words, in Visual Studio I could do this:

itor=m_ResourceMap.erase(itor);

In GCC 4.0, the erase function returns void, so I can't do that. Does that mean that the following map elements are shifted one backwards, so the iterator points automatically to the next element, or does that mean that I have to increment the iterator afterwards? The  [online STL Documentation](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Map.html) is not very concise on the subject and XCode does not seem to have any.

Thanks for your help,

Adrian

Comment: Asked and answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/180516/how-to-filter-items-from-a-stdmap

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No. You have to increment the iterator before erasing. Like this

```
m_ResourceMap.erase(itor++);
```

The iterator is invalidated by the erase, so you can't increment it afterwards.

Comment: I'm trying to make sense of the syntax. the itor++ is a postfix increment, so it erases itor, and then it should be invalid anyways, should it not?

Comment: Postfix: increment *and then* return a value of what the iterator used to point to. This value is what gets erased.

Answer (score 3):

By the look of things gcc is following the STL standard so I guess you'll have to change your code.

```
void erase(iterator pos)     Associative Container  Erases the element pointed to by pos.
```

Comment: A link to where you quoted that from would be useful.

Comment: Certainly I have to change the code, but how? That was the actual scope of my question...

Comment: http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Map.html and http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/stl/map/erase seem to agree on this Mark.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the DinkumWare implementation of the C++ standard library implementation of erase() is defined to return the iterator after the element that is to be removed.  This bit me as well and, when I asked DinkumWare about it, they said that it was a "conforming extension".

There are some STL containers (vectors for instance) that, when you perform insert or erase operations, can tend to invalidate all of the iterators for that container.  I cannot recall if the map is one of those but, if it is, there is a potentially insidious vulnerability to your method of erasing map elements in a loop.

Comment: Map won't invalidate iterators on either insert or erase. http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Map.html