# What happens with `map::iterator` when i remove entry from map?

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to filter items from a std::map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180516/how-to-filter-items-from-a-stdmap)
>   [What happens if you call erase() on a map element while iterating from begin to end?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263945/what-happens-if-you-call-erase-on-a-map-element-while-iterating-from-begin-to)

I have map of objects and i want to iterate over it and remove some entries.

```
typedef std::map<A,B> MapT;
MapT m;
MapT::iterator it;

for(it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); it++ ) {
    if( condition ) m.erase(it);
}
```

Can I do it in this way?

Comment: The iterator will be invalidated once you modify the map.

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263945/what-happens-if-you-call-erase-on-a-map-element-while-iterating-from-begin-to). (duplicate)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In case of `std::map` iterators and references to the erased elements are invalidated [23.1.2/8]. Your code uses the iterator *after* it has been invalidated, this results in an **Undefined Behavior**. In order to avoid this Undefined behavior the iterator needs to be incremented *before* it gets invalidated in the `erase()` call.

You need to use:

```
for(it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); ) {
    if( condition )
        m.erase(it++);
    else
        ++it;
}
```

Note that here `it++` increments `it` so that it refers to the next element but yields a copy of its original value. Thus, `it` doesn't refer to the element that is removed when `erase()` is called.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `MapT` is a `std::map`, then the iterator will be invalidated when erased.  The correct way to do this (`erase` in a loop) is to cache the iterator and increment prior to erasing it:

```
MapT m;
MapT::iterator it;

for(it = m.begin(); it != m.end();)
{
    if(condition)
    {
       MapT::iterator tmp = it++;
       m.erase(tmp);
    }
    else
    {
       ++it;
    } 
}
```